# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I have installed Live SASS Compiler extension for Visual Studio Code and having trouble trying to get the exetension to compile my scss files.

The problem is that I have bourbon + Neat folders inside a folder called libraries inside scss folder will print this error after save and compiled

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
on line 1 of sass/c:\xampp\htdocs\testsite\catalog\view\theme\spark\scss\go.scss

```
    @import "bourbon";
```

My settings is configured as per requirement.

```
(USER SETTINGS)
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
"window.zoomLevel": 2,
"liveSassCompile.settings.savePath": "/css",
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
"liveSassCompile.settings.format": "compressed",
"liveSassCompile.settings.extensionName": ".min.css",
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true
}
```

Inside go.scss has this import command

@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";

Can you please advice me how to get it working without throwing the errors?